# How to Add Listview in QuickAction Dialog in Android

Tags: android

Here find nice tutorial [QuickAction Dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).
I need to Add simple Listview in QuickAction Dialog.
Pls suggest me what I do.

I have create some stuff, but listview not show to full Dialog:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if its possible because *QuickAction* is preferably used to offer a minimum set of actions.

However, as an alternate, I would suggest you to make use of [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and integrate your `ListView` inside.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use PopupWindow here

Comment: @parag how you solved this,because i also want the feature like you,are u used PopWindows, pls suggest, Thanks in advance.

Comment: read [this](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/) blog post